# How to upload edittext content to Google Drive as a Google Doc?

Tags: java, android

I want to upload edittext content to Google Drive as a Google Doc, is there anyway to do this in Android?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things -

1. Create a File and save editText content in that file and save the file in your external storage.
2. Use Drive API to upload this file to google drive check the below document.

Check this link -  [google drive integration in android](https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/integrating-google-drive-api-in-android-applications-18024f42391c)